# React - creating accordion with bootstrap doesnt expand/close on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Iam trying to create a accordion from the bootstrap website in React. Iam following this website https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accordion-example

I copied their example code and it looks exactly just as the example on the website but the problem is when I click on the accordion nothing happends, it doesn't expand or close. Is there suppose to be a onClick function somewhere in the code that needs to be included?

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy the JS as well as the css code from bootstrap lib.

i suggest to use code from my google search bellow, create a component and just adapt the css style to bootstrap

https://www.google.it/search?q=accordion+example+jsfiddle&oq=accordion+example+jsf&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.12453j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

actually is very easy to build it

Comment: But where do you add the JS? do you just import it at the top of the class or create a method and paste the JS in?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm totally wrong here, as I am fairly new to web development- but I've used that accordion before and simply copying and pasting [their code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accordion-example) should do the trick, provided you have added the [proper link tags](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#css) from their "Getting Started" section in documentation set in your index.html (not just CSS but all of the JS links, too).

I hope this helps!!

Comment: he wants to add it into reactjs. from plain vanilla code to react there is a little diference